# OK to send and recv from two different threads without locking?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am working on some changes to a Python application in which requests are received via a socket and responses to the request are sent via the same socket. The changes are going to be such that `recv` and `send` would naturally end up being called from two different threads (`send` from one, `recv` from the other).

I haven't been able to find any *definitive* information about whether this can be expected to work without any explicit locking on the socket calls. I am aware of various SO questions where similar questions are asked but often they are hidden within case-specific scenarios with complicating factors and/or there appear to be differences of opinion. I haven't seen any answer that references any official documentation or some other trustworthy source.

In case it is relevant, Python is actually CPython, and this also needs to be reliable cross-platform (Windows and Linux).

Comment: @Victor Thanks but maybe my question is not clear. There is no first and second socket: as I said there is _a_ socket and `send` and `recv` are called on the _same_ socket. I am already using `threading`. `send` calls are entirely on one thread; `recv` are on the other. My question is simply whether this is thread safe.

Comment: @VictorRuiz Eh? What? Why? Why the buffer? What second socket? What does atomicity have to do with it?

Comment: @OP TCP sockets are full duplex. Unless the Python guys have screwed up badly, which would be rather difficult, you can send from one thread and receive from another thread with compete impunity.

Comment: Here is great [article](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) about non-blocking sockets in python. But I'm afraid it's linux specific

Comment: @NobbyNobbs There is no mention of non-blocking mode in the question.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, not non-blocking in my case.

Comment: @user207421 - regarding your reply to me, thanks - I think that nails it. Unless I am still not understanding something it simply _has_ to work as a consequence of TCP sockets being full duplex.